# Rails - link_to path based on object value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of User objects in an index view. For each user, I am displaying a name with a link_to call for editing the user like so:

```
<% @users.each do |u| %>
  <%= link_to u.name, edit_user_path(u) %><br/>
<% end %>
```

I want to use a different edit path based on the user's role attribute (e.g. employee, manager, etc). I have `edit_employee_path`, `edit_manager_path`, etc in my routes.

What's the best way dynamically determine the 2nd parameter to `link_to`? I can hack this up with a bunch of ugly if/else code but I want to do it the most idiomatic Rails way.

Comment: what is your controller and actions to where you want to make routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Helper module to determine the *_path method to run. For example:

```
module UsersHelper
  def edit_url(user)
    case user.role
    when :employee
      employee_edit_path(user)
    when :manager
      manager_edit_path(user)
    else
      edit_user_path(user)
    end
  end
end
```

If your path methods are named in a very consistent way, you might be able to invoke a dynamically-constructed method, such as:

```
<%= link_to u.name, send(:"#{u.role}_user_edit_path", u) %><br/>
```

but you'd need to be careful that a method with the appropriate name always exists.

Comment: I don't know how "careful" you'd need to be; validations should prevent your `role` from ever containing a value that isn't supported by a path helper. I guess that's sort of careful.

Comment: Yeah, I guess having validations to begin with could be considered "being careful" here

Comment: Exactly what I need Stuart M. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

how about a helper method

in your may be `users_helper` or any other helper of your choice

```
def edit_path_by_type(user)
   user.role == "Employee" ? edit_employee_path(user) : edit_manager_path(user)
end
```

and in your view

```
<%= link_to u.name, edit_path_by_type(u) %>
```